# YII2: Dropdownlist with multiple primary key

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2

I Have table with multiple primary key. I already put primary key function in my model like this.

```
class Block extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
...
public static function primaryKey()
{
  return [
     'province_id',
     'city_id',
     'area_id',
     'block_id',
  ];
}
```

This is my form for search of ListView

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'block_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Block::find()->all(), 'block_id','name'), ['prompt'=>'Choose Block'])->label(false);?>
```

I can't get all block for my search form. How should I change 'block_id' to get all of my block in dropdownlist?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `Block::find()->all()` maybe use `asArray()`?

Comment: Give up using activeRecord already. asArray didn't give all row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of try, I give up on use ActiveRecord and use sql query instead.

My search listview code looks like this.

```
use yii\db\Query;
.....
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;
$sql = $connection ->createCommand('SELECT CONCAT(province_id,".",city_id,".",area_id,".",block_id) AS block_full, name FROM block');
$query = $sql->queryAll();
echo $form->field($model, 'block_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($query, 'block_full','name'), ['prompt'=>'Choose Block'])->label(false);
```

I used CONCAT to make filter more easy in model. I will explode block_full to get proper id for each primary key.